# What is the sharpest bend in a tram track?

Tags: public-transport, where-on-earth

I recently received an email about track maintenance to the tram network. It included the following sentence:

> Track at the corner of Fletcher Gate and Victoria Street – believed to be one of the sharpest bends on a UK tram system - will be replaced to ensure tram services can continue to be provided safely and reliably.

Here is the location of said curve: [(52.9532937, -1.1453881)](https://goo.gl/maps/Cp4BPwh8ZLbA1FS79). I’d estimate it to be around a 20m radius.

I am now, of course, interested in what the sharpest (smallest radius) bend is in a tram track.

I’d be interested in tram tracks from around the world, although it would be nice to know if the Fletcher Gate / Victoria Street bend is the sharpest in the U.K.

Comment: Similarly tight: https://goo.gl/maps/CwkQ5iASWLz9FrBWA. Edwin_m also thinks it’s the lace market corner: https://www.railforums.co.uk/threads/trivia-what-are-the-sharpest-curves-on-network-rail-routes.103979/page-2

Comment: 25m radius is super common, but that one you linked has roughly 18m radius. Here's one with 17.5m radius, but it's in a museum: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Hannoversches+Stra%C3%9Fenbahn-Museum+e.V./@52.2900481,9.9317977,81m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1

Comment: San Francisco has several that, based on rough Google Maps measurement, look like about 15-16m.  For instance [9th and Judah](https://goo.gl/maps/oTmPPq4Frzxj5WSy5), [17th and Market at Castro](https://goo.gl/maps/GoiERSmQEZoDr8UA6), [30th and San Jose](https://goo.gl/maps/BgB5WzrghEKF8ajw6), and a slightly larger 180 degree turnaround at [Judah and Great Highway](https://goo.gl/maps/M9NdRd9Y6huGGrAFA).  Would they count?  Hmm, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_Municipal_Railway) quotes it as 13.1m.

Comment: Wikipedia's [source](http://onlinepubs.trb.org/Onlinepubs/tcrp/tcrp_rpt_02.pdf) also mentions Newark at 10m and Toronto at 11m, as well as Hilmar's 10m figure for Boston's Green Line.  The document is dated 1995 so the layouts may have changed since then.

Comment: Newark seems to have a pretty tight corner at Mulberry and Raymond, but it's underground so hard to measure on a map.  Toronto has got some tight ones, e.g. [Church and King](https://goo.gl/maps/w4nGRkDjA6XAE7X27) for which 12-13m looks plausible.

Comment: Lisbon would seem a good candidate to check, with some tracks only being navigable by tiny trams as they go up steep, twisty streets

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the Green Line in Boston? According to Wikipedia it has a minimum radius of 10m. That must either be the Boylston Street turn or the entrance to North Station. There is an actual STOP sign at the tunnel entrance and then the speed limit in the tunnel is posted at 3 miles/hour. The ride at this spot is accompanied by a good awful squeal that takes your eardrums out.

Comment: I think that may have been at the Lechmere turnaround, which would make this out-of-date, as that loop of track has been taken up as part of the Green Line Extension project.